# Run a jquery plugin with same state change in ionic

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic 1 to create app. There is a page "post" where I am running a jquery plugin roundSlider.

my code is

```
.controller('PostCtrl', function($rootScope,$scope,$http,$state,$ionicHistory,$ionicLoading,$window,$timeout,$ionicSideMenuDelegate,$window,$stateParams) {
    angular.element("#shape").roundSlider({             
        sliderType: "min-range",
        handleShape: "round",
        radius:75,
        value: 1,
        handleSize: "+25",
        editableTooltip: false,
        width: 8,
        startAngle: 90,
        min:1,
        max:100,
        endAngle:+440,
        change: function(event) {
            $scope.wheelvalue = event.value;

        }
    });

    $scope.nextPost = function(subjectid){
        $state.transitionTo($state.current, {'post_id': post_id}, {
            reload: true,
            inherit: false,
            notify: true
        });

    }   

})
```

There is a link "next post" and clicking on this user can go to next post which is same page just post_id is changing.

I have tried "next post" link as

```
<a href="app.post/{{next_post_id}}">next post</a>
```

as well onclick event on link as

```
<a  href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="nextPost ({{next_post_id}})"> next post</a>
```

But jquery slider failed to load. It's just loading first time and not loading on second post.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is shown some error at the console?

Comment: No , there is no error.

Comment: Do you have any clue ?

Comment: @JoseRojas , can you please see the problem ?

Comment: Can you post the link of your jquery plugin please?

Comment: Is this issue resolved now ? Otherwise update a plunker link to showcase the demo, which helps to identify and resolve the issue.